# Import JSX file from another JSX file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am quite new to React and am currently playing around with a PoC to see if it meets our needs. It seems that whenever I try to import a React component from another package into my App component it gives me this error.

```
../myawesomeapp-ui/components/Checkout/Footer/Footer.jsx 21:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|     return (
>         <div id="checkout__footer">
|             <div className="checkout__footer_back-to-shop">
|                 <p>...</p>
```

My setup uses yarn workspaces to separate different parts of our project into different packages. The 3 packages I have set up are `@myawesomeapp/util` which contains sass assets and jsx reusable services etc, `@myawesomeapp/ui` which uses React and Storybook to develop reusable components, and `@myawesomeapp/checkout` which contains a basic React app setup using Create React App.

The Storybook components seem to be able to import resources from `@myawesomeapp/util` just fine (other than needing to specify 'file-loader!' before the import path for png images). However, trying to import the components from the `@myawesomeapp/ui` package I get the error above. In both packages subfolders I have this webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.jsx"),
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".scss", ".sass"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    "file-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

This is an example of the footer component that causes the error in "@myawesomeapp/ui":

```
import React from 'react';
import PaymentLogos from 'file-loader!@amorelie/util/assets/images/payment.png';

export default CheckoutFooter = () => {
    return (
        <div id="checkout__footer">
            <div className="checkout__footer_back-to-shop">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

And this is the component I am trying to render it in:

```
import React from 'react';

import { CheckoutFooter } from '@myawesomeapp/ui/components';


function App() {
    return (
        <div id="myawesomeapp__checkout">
            <CheckoutFooter />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Is there some kind of issue when trying to import jsx components into other jsx components or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are using default export, remove the `{ }` during your import

Comment: Do you have the react plugin installed for babel, `babel/preset-react` which includes the syntax plugins for it to understand jsx?

Comment: Yes, I have "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0" in my devDependancies

Comment: What I find strange is that it is working fine rendering the App component, it's only the imported components it's throwing errors on.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not using my eyes. You might want to install and use these presets in your webpack.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it all kinds of ways. Always get the same error :/ I think I've narrowed it down to it being something to do with the import statement in the App.jsx file. If I remove that it renders fine. And if I don't try to render them in the App component it still throws the error, so it must be an issue with this import statement in particular

Comment: Are you sure your code is being transpiled by Babel correctly? Import/export is an es2015 feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import can you maybe post your webpack file here?

Comment: @FrankWaalkens OP's  webpack file is the second code block in the question

Comment: Yes, I included my Webpack config in the question. After a few more tests I realised that if I move the component into that package and reference it using a relative path it works. It appears to be an issue with referencing it via an alias. Which doesn't seem to make much sense because all it does is add a symlink to the node_modules directory, so it should be the same as importing it via a relative path

Comment: You made a symlink using NPM link? if not, you can try that aswell. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html